# Force Initializing Class to Use Method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Is there a way to force the class/component initializing a certain class to call one of its functions?

Ex:

```
class Car
{
  public destroy(){...}
}

class Bomb extends React.Component<...>
{
  private car: Car = new Car();
}
```

I wish for whoever initializes Car to call destroy() at some point in the initializing class (Bomb, in this case).

Comment: Not in any straightforward way, no.  Have you heard of a language with such a feature?

Comment: This reminds me of [microsoft/TypeScript#21388](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21388), which also is not possible directly. I'm not sure if there's any way to even express something similar in TypeScript.  *Where* in `Bomb` do you want `car.destroy()` to appear?

Comment: I am little confused. Sounds like OP want to call `destroy` during the initialization of `Bomb` which is also initialization of `Car`, so, should it not call `destroy` in the constructor of the `Car`? @jcalz interesting read BTW.

Comment: When is the 'some point'? If you're saying you want the method to be called during the initialization of the ```Car``` class when ```Bomb``` class is initialized, then just call the method in the constructor of the class using ```this.destroy()```

Comment: @mightyandweakcoder I need a specific method in all of 'those types' of classes that are initialized in Bomb to be called at the very least during/in componentWillUnmount() in the Bomb component. Anywhere will work.